# Run DynamoDB Local with the java command on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, amazon-web-services, terminal, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run DynamoDB local on a MAC.
The [Amazon official blog](http://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/) says I have to download the jar file and run the following command:

```
$ java –Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

But I got the following error on MAC OS X terminal:

> Error: Could not find or load main class –Djava.library.path=.

Wut? The command seams not to recognise the -D parameter.. why?

I'm also working on Linux (Fedora) and I never had any problem with it.

On MAC OS X, `java -version` gives me `java version "1.8.0_11"`

What could be the problem? (I don't know that much with java commands)

---

**Edit 1**: Thanks to @Swapnil, we can notice that there is a typo error on the Amazon blog, they used a wrong dash character ([EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) unicode U+2013) for the `-D` argument. Note that the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) (not the blog) does not have the typo error and also refers to an [up-to-date binary](http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest).

**Edit 2**: With the correct dash, the argument is interpreted by java, but I still got a (different) error message during runtime:

> SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[AKID_eu-west-1.db]: error running job
>   queue com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load
>   library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in
>   java.library.path

I fixed it like that:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib/  -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

It's now finally working... Amazon documentation have some problems..

Comment: You can see this play out in this other Stack Overflow answer, which also covers how to programatically set `java.library.path` if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353377/3679676

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below seems to work for me on my Mac OS X -

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar your_jar
```

Well, the dash character you've used in `–D` seems to be a different character altogether. That's probably causing the problem.

Comment: Ohh!! Yeah thank you so much! On the [Amazon blog](http://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/), the dash used in –D is in fact a **EN DASH** (U+2013), that's why the argument has been misinterpreted. I've been driven crazy with this! Thank you! <3

Answer (score 2):

For Mac, it might work without -Djava.library.path option. Try the following command:

```
java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

Also, the link to the download in the blog does not point to the latest DynamoDB Local version. You can get the latest version from [here](http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest). This link is also present in the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html).

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the links, but it's **not working** without the -Djava.library.path argument

Answer (score 0):

I had to change two things:
set up `-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib/`

and change the the library name from `libsqlite4java-osx` to `libsqlite4java-osx-x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting the `-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib/` I had to copy `libsqlite4java-osx-10.4.jnilib` to `libsqlite4java-osx-x86_64.dylib`.